# How do I implement a "Frame effect" in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I would like to reproduce this effect :
[image]

How can I do with xaml ?

(note that the text can be variable)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: no need to add [xaml][silverlight] on the title, the tags already serve this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with a combination of Border and Grid panels:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="0,7,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="Lorem Ipsum..." Margin="20"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Background="White" Margin="10,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="My Title" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the problem is that "my title" is striked out

Comment: You have to put the title inside a border with white background, otherwise the frame border will strike out the text. If you try my code you'll see that the text is not striked out.